# Why $\Bbb{E}[\xi1_A]=\int_A\xi dP$

Tags: measure-theory, probability-theory

$\xi$ is an integrable random variable on $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$. Why $\Bbb{E}[\xi1_A]=\int_A\xi dP$ for some measurable set A.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Recall the definition of $\int_A$, for measurable $A$:

$$\int_A f \, \mathrm dP = \int 1_A f \, \mathrm dP$$

and hence:

$$\Bbb E[\xi 1_A] = \int \xi 1_A \,\mathrm dP = \int_A \xi \, \mathrm dP$$

Comment: What's the definition of $\int_A$?

Comment: @Steven: it is the second line of Lord_Farin's answer.

Comment: I've edited it to make that more explicit.

Comment: Is $\int_A f \, \mathrm dP$ the integral of $f$ with respect to measure $P$?

Comment: @Steven: It is the integral of $1_A f$ wrt $P$. Alternatively, one might say it is the integral of $f$ wrt $P$ on $A$, or the integral of $f$ wrt $1_A P$.

Comment: @Lord_Farin I'm just very confused with the definition. What does the $A$ in $\int_A$ stand for?

Comment: @Lord_Farin What's the difference between $\int_A f \, \mathrm dP$ and $\int f \, \mathrm dP$?

Comment: $A$ is a measurable set. For example, it could be the set $\{f > t\}$ for some measurable function/random variable $f$ and $t \in \Bbb R$. Then $\int_A f \, \mathrm dP$ calculates something like $\Bbb E[f \mid f \ge t]$, while $\int f\,\mathrm dP$ calculates $\Bbb E[f]$. It might be a good idea to have this conversation in chat but you need 20 rep. for that...

Comment: I have another account over 20 rep... can I use that?..

Comment: Note that $\int_A f\,\mathrm dP$ could have been defined as the integral $\int f\,\mathrm dP_A$ on the measure space $(A,\mathcal{F}_A,P_A)$. If that's the case, then the equality needs some justification.

Comment: @Steven Yes that'd be fine.

Comment: @Lord_Farin so $\int_A f \, \mathrm dP$ gives conditional expectation?

Comment: @Steven: Almost. Conditional expectation $\Bbb E[f|A]$ is given by $\dfrac{\int_A f\,\mathrm dP}{P(A)}$. But please, join mathematics chat so that we won't clutter up this question further with a discussion.